# CentOS 7 upgrade to RockyLinux 8 fails using leapp/elevate

Tags: rocky-linux

This URL : [How to upgrade Centos 7 to Rocky Linux 8](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/how-to-upgrade-centos-7-to-rocky-linux-8.html?utm_content=cmp-true) claims it should be possible to migrate directly from CentOS 7 to Rocky 8.

I created a local repository of RockyLinux 8 on one machine in my network, and made it available through Apache to the rest of the network.
Did the same for the Elevate repository.
I need to do this because I have to migrate a lot of servers that are not connected to the internet....

On the CentOS 7 machine I want to migrate I created a new repo file in /etc/yum.repos.d, pointing to the elevate repository on the other machine.
Thus, I was able to install leapp-upgrade leapp-data-rocky.

Next was the leap preupgrade command :

```
leapp preupgrade --enablerepo rocky8-baseos --enablerepo rocky8-appstream --no-rhsm
```

(I changed the file leapp_upgrade_repositories.repo in the directory /etc/leapp/files to point to my local Rocky repository)

This runs happily for some time, I can see rpm packages being installed in /var/lib/leapp/el8userspace, but then the actor dnf_transaction_check starts to work, and fails.

I get a lot of errors I cannot explain (see below).
Made sure that CentOS 7 was at the latest level of patching, so was Rocky 8...

Does anyone know where I should look for a solution, because I really do not have a clue ?

```
2023-02-21 11:04:37.864177 [ERROR] Actor: dnf_transaction_check
Message: DNF execution failed with non zero exit code.
STDOUT:
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:40 ago on Tue Feb 21 11:03:52 2023.

STDERR:
No matches found for the following disable plugin patterns: subscription-manager
Repository extras is listed more than once in the configuration
Warning: Package marked by Leapp to install not found in repositories metadata: rpcgen 
python3-pyxattr
Warning: Package marked by Leapp to upgrade not found in repositories metadata: gpg-pubkey
Transaction check:

Problem 1: conflicting requests
- nothing provides perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.24.4) needed by perl-Math-BigRat-0.2614-2.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.noarch
Problem 2: cannot install the best candidate for the job
- nothing provides perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.24.4) needed by perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-1001.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.x86_64
- nothing provides libperl.so.5.24()(64bit) needed by perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-1001.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.x86_64
Problem 3: cannot install the best candidate for the job
- nothing provides perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.24.4) needed by perl-Term-Cap-1.17-396.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.noarch
Problem 4: package perl-Net-Ping-2.72-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.noarch requires perl(constant), but none of the providers can be installed
- cannot install the best update candidate for package perl-constant-1.27-2.el7.noarch
- perl-constant-1.27-2.el7.noarch does not belong to a distupgrade repository
- conflicting requests
- nothing provides perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.24.4) needed by perl-constant-1.33-1001.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.noarch
Problem 5: package perl-bignum-0.51-439.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.noarch requires perl(Math::BigRat) >= 0.12, but none of the providers can be installed
- perl-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64 does not belong to a distupgrade repository
- conflicting requests
- nothing provides perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.24.4) needed by perl-Math-BigRat-0.2614-2.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.noarch
Problem 6: problem with installed package perl-Pod-Escapes-1:1.04-299.el7_9.noarch
- cannot install the best update candidate for package perl-Pod-Escapes-1:1.04-299.el7_9.noarch
- perl-Pod-Escapes-1:1.04-299.el7_9.noarch does not belong to a distupgrade repository
- nothing provides perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.24.4) needed by perl-Pod-Escapes-1:1.07-396.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.noarch
Problem 7: problem with installed package perl-Text-ParseWords-3.29-4.el7.noarch
- cannot install the best update candidate for package perl-Text-ParseWords-3.29-4.el7.noarch
- perl-Text-ParseWords-3.29-4.el7.noarch does not belong to a distupgrade repository
- nothing provides perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.24.4) needed by perl-Text-ParseWords-3.30-396.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.noarch
|
|
|
Problem 37: cannot install the best update candidate for package perl-Pod-Usage-1.63-3.el7.noarch
- problem with installed package perl-Pod-Usage-1.63-3.el7.noarch
- package perl-Pod-Usage-4:2.01-1.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.noarch requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.32.1), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(Encode), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:3.08-461.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(MIME::Base64), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:2.97-3.el8.i686 requires perl(MIME::Base64), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:2.97-3.el8.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.26()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-396.el8.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.26()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- cannot install both perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 and perl-libs-4:5.26.3-421.el8.x86_64
- package perl-Encode-2.51-7.el7.x86_64 requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.16.3), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64 requires libgdbm.so.4()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- cannot install both gdbm-1:1.18-2.el8.x86_64 and gdbm-1.10-8.el7.x86_64
- package python3-libs-3.6.8-48.el8_7.rocky.0.x86_64 requires gdbm(x86-64) >= 1:1.13, but none of the providers can be installed
- package python3-libdnf-0.63.0-11.1.el8.x86_64 requires libpython3.6m.so.1.0()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package python3-libs-3.6.8-18.el7.x86_64 requires libreadline.so.6()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- cannot install both readline-7.0-10.el8.x86_64 and readline-6.2-11.el7.x86_64
- package gnupg2-2.2.20-3.el8_6.x86_64 requires libreadline.so.7()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package rpm-build-libs-4.14.3-24.el8_7.x86_64 requires /usr/bin/gpg2, but none of the providers can be installed
- package python3-rpm-4.14.3-24.el8_7.x86_64 requires librpmbuild.so.8()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package python3-rpm-4.14.3-24.el8_7.x86_64 requires librpmsign.so.8()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package python3-hawkey-0.63.0-11.1.el8.x86_64 requires python3-libdnf = 0.63.0-11.1.el8, but none of the providers can be installed
- gnupg2-2.0.22-5.el7_5.x86_64 does not belong to a distupgrade repository
- conflicting requests
- nothing provides perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.24.4) needed by perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-1001.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.x86_64
- nothing provides libperl.so.5.24()(64bit) needed by perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-1001.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.x86_64
- perl-Pod-Usage-1.63-3.el7.noarch does not belong to a distupgrade repository
Problem 38: cannot install the best update candidate for package perl-Pod-Simple-1:3.28-4.el7.noarch
- problem with installed package perl-Pod-Simple-1:3.28-4.el7.noarch
- package perl-Pod-Simple-1:3.42-1.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.noarch requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.32.1), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(Encode), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-2.51-7.el7.x86_64 requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.16.3), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:3.08-461.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(MIME::Base64), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:2.97-3.el8.i686 requires perl(MIME::Base64), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64 requires libperl.so()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64 requires perl-libs = 4:5.16.3-299.el7_9, but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:2.97-3.el8.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.26()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-396.el8.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.26()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- cannot install both perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 and perl-libs-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64
- cannot install both perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 and perl-libs-4:5.26.3-421.el8.x86_64
- nothing provides perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.24.4) needed by perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-1001.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.x86_64
- nothing provides libperl.so.5.24()(64bit) needed by perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-1001.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.x86_64
- perl-Pod-Simple-1:3.28-4.el7.noarch does not belong to a distupgrade repository
Problem 39: cannot install the best update candidate for package perl-Pod-Perldoc-3.20-4.el7.noarch
- problem with installed package perl-Pod-Perldoc-3.20-4.el7.noarch
- package perl-Pod-Perldoc-3.28.01-443.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.noarch requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.32.1), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(Encode), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-2.51-7.el7.x86_64 requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.16.3), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:3.08-461.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(MIME::Base64), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:2.97-3.el8.i686 requires perl(MIME::Base64), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64 requires libperl.so()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64 requires perl-libs = 4:5.16.3-299.el7_9, but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:2.97-3.el8.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.26()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-396.el8.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.26()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- cannot install both perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 and perl-libs-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64
- cannot install both perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 and perl-libs-4:5.26.3-421.el8.x86_64
- nothing provides perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.24.4) needed by perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-1001.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.x86_64
- nothing provides libperl.so.5.24()(64bit) needed by perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-1001.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.x86_64
- perl-Pod-Perldoc-3.20-4.el7.noarch does not belong to a distupgrade repository
Problem 40: cannot install the best update candidate for package perl-PathTools-3.40-5.el7.x86_64
- problem with installed package perl-PathTools-3.40-5.el7.x86_64
- package perl-PathTools-3.78-439.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.32.1), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-PathTools-3.78-439.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.32()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(Encode), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-2.51-7.el7.x86_64 requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.16.3), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:3.08-461.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(MIME::Base64), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:2.97-3.el8.i686 requires perl(MIME::Base64), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64 requires libperl.so()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64 requires perl-libs = 4:5.16.3-299.el7_9, but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:2.97-3.el8.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.26()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-396.el8.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.26()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- cannot install both perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 and perl-libs-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64
- cannot install both perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 and perl-libs-4:5.26.3-421.el8.x86_64
- nothing provides perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.24.4) needed by perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-1001.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.x86_64
- nothing provides libperl.so.5.24()(64bit) needed by perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-1001.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.x86_64
- perl-PathTools-3.40-5.el7.x86_64 does not belong to a distupgrade repository
Problem 41: cannot install the best update candidate for package perl-Getopt-Long-2.40-3.el7.noarch
- problem with installed package perl-Getopt-Long-2.40-3.el7.noarch
- package perl-Getopt-Long-1:2.52-1.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.noarch requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.32.1), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(Encode), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-2.51-7.el7.x86_64 requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.16.3), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:3.08-461.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(MIME::Base64), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:2.97-3.el8.i686 requires perl(MIME::Base64), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64 requires libperl.so()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64 requires perl-libs = 4:5.16.3-299.el7_9, but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:2.97-3.el8.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.26()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-396.el8.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.26()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- cannot install both perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 and perl-libs-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64
- cannot install both perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 and perl-libs-4:5.26.3-421.el8.x86_64
- nothing provides perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.24.4) needed by perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-1001.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.x86_64
- nothing provides libperl.so.5.24()(64bit) needed by perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-1001.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.x86_64
- perl-Getopt-Long-2.40-3.el7.noarch does not belong to a distupgrade repository
Problem 42: cannot install the best update candidate for package perl-File-Temp-0.23.01-3.el7.noarch
- problem with installed package perl-File-Temp-0.23.01-3.el7.noarch
- package perl-File-Temp-1:0.231.100-1.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.noarch requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.32.1), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(Encode), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-2.51-7.el7.x86_64 requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.16.3), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:3.08-461.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(MIME::Base64), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:2.97-3.el8.i686 requires perl(MIME::Base64), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64 requires libperl.so()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64 requires perl-libs = 4:5.16.3-299.el7_9, but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:2.97-3.el8.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.26()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-396.el8.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.26()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- cannot install both perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 and perl-libs-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64
- cannot install both perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 and perl-libs-4:5.26.3-421.el8.x86_64
- nothing provides perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.24.4) needed by perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-1001.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.x86_64
- nothing provides libperl.so.5.24()(64bit) needed by perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-1001.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.x86_64
- perl-File-Temp-0.23.01-3.el7.noarch does not belong to a distupgrade repository
Problem 43: cannot install the best update candidate for package perl-File-Path-2.09-2.el7.noarch
- problem with installed package perl-File-Path-2.09-2.el7.noarch
- package perl-File-Path-2.16-439.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.noarch requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.32.1), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(Encode), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-2.51-7.el7.x86_64 requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.16.3), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:3.08-461.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(MIME::Base64), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:2.97-3.el8.i686 requires perl(MIME::Base64), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64 requires libperl.so()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64 requires perl-libs = 4:5.16.3-299.el7_9, but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:2.97-3.el8.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.26()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-396.el8.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.26()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- cannot install both perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 and perl-libs-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64
- cannot install both perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 and perl-libs-4:5.26.3-421.el8.x86_64
- nothing provides perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.24.4) needed by perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-1001.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.x86_64
- nothing provides libperl.so.5.24()(64bit) needed by perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-1001.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.x86_64
- perl-File-Path-2.09-2.el7.noarch does not belong to a distupgrade repository
Problem 44: cannot install the best update candidate for package perl-Exporter-5.68-3.el7.noarch
- problem with installed package perl-Exporter-5.68-3.el7.noarch
- package perl-Exporter-5.74-458.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.noarch requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.32.1), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(Encode), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-2.51-7.el7.x86_64 requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.16.3), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:3.08-461.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(MIME::Base64), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:2.97-3.el8.i686 requires perl(MIME::Base64), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64 requires libperl.so()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64 requires perl-libs = 4:5.16.3-299.el7_9, but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:2.97-3.el8.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.26()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-396.el8.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.26()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- cannot install both perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 and perl-libs-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64
- cannot install both perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 and perl-libs-4:5.26.3-421.el8.x86_64
- nothing provides perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.24.4) needed by perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-1001.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.x86_64
- nothing provides libperl.so.5.24()(64bit) needed by perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-1001.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.x86_64
- perl-Exporter-5.68-3.el7.noarch does not belong to a distupgrade repository
Problem 45: cannot install the best update candidate for package perl-Carp-1.26-244.el7.noarch
- problem with installed package perl-Carp-1.26-244.el7.noarch
- package perl-Carp-1.50-439.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.noarch requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.32.1), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(Encode), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-2.51-7.el7.x86_64 requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.16.3), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:3.08-461.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(MIME::Base64), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:2.97-3.el8.i686 requires perl(MIME::Base64), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64 requires libperl.so()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64 requires perl-libs = 4:5.16.3-299.el7_9, but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:2.97-3.el8.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.26()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-396.el8.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.26()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- cannot install both perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 and perl-libs-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64
- cannot install both perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 and perl-libs-4:5.26.3-421.el8.x86_64
- nothing provides perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.24.4) needed by perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-1001.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.x86_64
- nothing provides libperl.so.5.24()(64bit) needed by perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-1001.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.x86_64
- perl-Carp-1.26-244.el7.noarch does not belong to a distupgrade repository
Problem 46: problem with installed package perl-Encode-2.51-7.el7.x86_64
- cannot install the best update candidate for package perl-Encode-2.51-7.el7.x86_64
- package perl-Encode-4:3.08-461.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.32.1), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:3.08-461.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.32()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(Encode), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-2.51-7.el7.x86_64 requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.16.3), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:3.08-461.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(MIME::Base64), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:2.97-3.el8.i686 requires perl(MIME::Base64), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64 requires libperl.so()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64 requires perl-libs = 4:5.16.3-299.el7_9, but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:2.97-3.el8.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.26()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-396.el8.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.26()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- cannot install both perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 and perl-libs-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64
- cannot install both perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 and perl-libs-4:5.26.3-421.el8.x86_64
- nothing provides perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.24.4) needed by perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-1001.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.x86_64
- nothing provides libperl.so.5.24()(64bit) needed by perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-1001.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.x86_64
Problem 47: package perl-libs-4:5.26.3-421.el8.x86_64 requires perl(Encode), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:2.97-3.el8.x86_64 requires perl(Getopt::Long), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:2.97-3.el8.i686 requires perl(Getopt::Long), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Getopt-Long-1:2.50-4.el8.noarch requires perl(Pod::Usage) >= 1.14, but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Pod-Usage-4:1.69-395.el8.noarch requires perl-Pod-Perldoc, but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-threads-1:2.21-2.el8.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.26()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Pod-Perldoc-3.28-396.el8.noarch requires perl(HTTP::Tiny), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-2.51-7.el7.x86_64 requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.16.3), but none of the providers can be installed
- problem with installed package perl-threads-1.87-4.el7.x86_64
- cannot install the best update candidate for package perl-Getopt-Long-2.40-3.el7.noarch
- cannot install the best update candidate for package perl-HTTP-Tiny-0.033-3.el7.noarch
- cannot install the best update candidate for package perl-Pod-Perldoc-3.20-4.el7.noarch
- cannot install the best update candidate for package perl-Pod-Usage-1.63-3.el7.noarch
- package perl-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64 requires perl(Time::HiRes), but none of the providers can be installed
- cannot install the best update candidate for package perl-threads-1.87-4.el7.x86_64
- package perl-Encode-4:3.08-461.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.32.1), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:3.08-461.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.32()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Getopt-Long-1:2.52-1.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.noarch requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.32.1), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-HTTP-Tiny-0.078-1.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.noarch requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.32.1), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Pod-Perldoc-3.28.01-443.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.noarch requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.32.1), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Pod-Usage-4:2.01-1.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.noarch requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.32.1), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Time-HiRes-4:1.9764-459.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.32.1), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Time-HiRes-4:1.9764-459.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.32()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-threads-1:2.25-457.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.32.1), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-threads-1:2.25-457.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.32()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(Encode), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:3.08-461.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 requires perl(MIME::Base64), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:2.97-3.el8.i686 requires perl(MIME::Base64), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64 requires libperl.so()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64 requires perl-libs = 4:5.16.3-299.el7_9, but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-Encode-4:2.97-3.el8.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.26()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- package perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-396.el8.x86_64 requires libperl.so.5.26()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
- cannot install both perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 and perl-libs-4:5.16.3-299.el7_9.x86_64
- cannot install both perl-libs-4:5.32.1-471.module+el8.6.0+879+823e3012.x86_64 and perl-libs-4:5.26.3-421.el8.x86_64
- nothing provides perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.24.4) needed by perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-1001.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.x86_64
- nothing provides libperl.so.5.24()(64bit) needed by perl-MIME-Base64-3.15-1001.module+el8.6.0+882+2fa1e48f.x86_64
- perl-Time-HiRes-4:1.9725-3.el7.x86_64 does not belong to a distupgrade repository
- perl-HTTP-Tiny-0.033-3.el7.noarch does not belong to a distupgrade repository
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you were lead astray by an outdated article that has not been revised recently. I happen to use **leapp** and have performed OS migrations, via **convert2rhel**, as well as major distro upgrades via **leapp**.

I'd suggest you reference this specific article if you want more recent discussion specific to RockyLinux 8. The gist is they say this won't work as described in the Alma blog.

[How to migrate CentOS 7 to Rock Linux 8](https://forums.rockylinux.org/t/how-to-migrate-centos-7-to-rock-linux-8/3470)

---

Separately I have converted systems without a complete OS reinstall. However it's a much longer and more convoluted process to follow and I don't generally suggest this instead of a full OS installation along with restoring data and any configuration tuning. However I will provide the basic bullet points anyway in case an OS reinstallation is definitely not on the table as an option. I suggest testing this first on a VM with snapshots. This will aide in testing any steps required to resolve the **leapp** upgrade report findings without trying to undo any unsuccessful tests, just rollback to the snapshot and try again.

1. Obtain a RHEL production or developers subscription.
2. Following the [RHEL guide to convert to RHEL](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/linux-platforms/enterprise-linux/migration-process/convert2rhel-how-to-convert-from-centos-linux-to-red-hat-enterprise-linux) and use **convert2rhel** and migrate CentOS 7 to RHEL 7.
3. Follow the [RHEL guides to upgrade from RHEL 7 to RHEL 8](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html-single/upgrading_from_rhel_7_to_rhel_8/index) and use **leapp** to perform a major version upgrade.
4. Follow the [How to Migrate to Rocky Linux guide](https://docs.rockylinux.org/guides/migrate2rocky/) and use **migrate2rocky** to convert from RHEL to RockyLinux.